# convert IE6 and 7 Hack into an IE6, 7 and 8 hack

Tags: css, internet-explorer

In my css code i have tose hack that i want to affect IE6/7

```
#topmenu li a.activa,
#topmenu li a.activa:hover{
    *background: url(../nImg/comunHomeSprite.png) no-repeat;
    *background-position: right -2169px;  
    *float:left;
    *margin:0;
    *padding:0;
    *margin-left:10px;
}
```

Is there a simple way to convert them into IE8 also??

Comment: Couldn't you choose conditional comments instead?

Comment: I recommend to use conditional comments, so that non-IE browsers will not attempt to parse the invalid CSS properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* IE8 */ @media \0screen { #topmenu li a.activa, @media \0screen #topmenu li a.activa:hover {
  background: url(../nImg/comunHomeSprite.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: right -2169px;  
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  margin-left:10px;
} }
```

I prefer this way personally as the attributes are still standard CSS and you need only change them once instead of however many different hacks you have. It can get a bit unwieldy otherwise.

Comment: Really? I use these hacks quite regularly. They're also documented at http://dimox.net/personal-css-hacks-for-ie6-ie7-ie8/, http://www.devblog.co/internet-explorer-css-hacks/ IE8 one at http://www.coding4streetcred.com/blog/post/CSS-Cross-Browser-Hacks.aspx

Comment: Just noticed I missed a pair of `{}`'s, might have had something to do with it!

Comment: no well just copyed the selectors... might be cause of IE-Tester?

Answer (score 3):

If you *must* use hacks, then read this: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/

But note that CSS hacks are considered evil.

Conditional comments are a good alternative. They are easy to use, and guaranteed to work properly.

You can't put conditional comments directly into a stylesheet, but what you can do is define a class in your `<body>` tag using conditional comments, which you can then reference in the CSS:

Write your HTML `<body>` tag like this:

```
<!--[if IE 6]> <body class="ie6 ltie7 ltie8 ltie9"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if IE 7]> <body class="ie7 ltie8 ltie9"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if IE 8]> <body class="ie8 ltie9"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if IE 9]> <body class="ie9"> <![endif]-->  
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <body> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then in your CSS, you can reference the relevant IE class in your selectors, and you'll have completely valid CSS code:

```
#topmenu li a.activa:hover {
   /*normal styles here*/
}

.ie8 #topmenu li a.activa:hover {
   /*IE8-specific styles here*/
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1, this is a much better solution than hacks and I use it on several sites.

Comment: i could use it. but we already use tags in body to define language and other options... it's just too expensive to change it. but i will just use rounded images -i hate explorer-

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet - re your comment: is this is all about doing rounded corners? If so, you might want to look up [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

Comment: haha, nice you put that out. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877917/piecss3-not-rounding-in-local  (it's not a personal work. i have boss and everything i can't risk it won't work in local....) thanks dough

Comment: hehe :) ah, I didn't notice the same user name.  :-p

Answer (score 2):

Found this

```
selector {
    prop: value; /* real browsers */
    _prop: value; /* ie6 */
    *prop: value; /* ie6 ie7 */
    prop: value\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

don't know if this addresses IE9

Comment: is it combinable with important! ??

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Don't know really. Didn't test it.